# Why does this inductive proof fail?

Tags: logic, induction

I would like to spell out where the following inductive argument goes wrong, but I am not sure how to.

Goal: Show Ga<sub>10</sub>

(1) Assume that Fa<sub>1</sub>

(2) Assume that Fa<sub>n</sub> $\to$ Ga<sub>n+1</sub>

(3) By induction, Ga<sub>10</sub>.

What makes this argument invalid?

Comment: Could you explain your notation further? As this question is written I am unable to understand what exactly you are trying to prove.

Comment: Is Fa=Ga? Also, the way you prove by induction, you do not assume that the base of induction holds, you prove that it holds. Same for the step of induction.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your notation, but it appears that you prove/assume $Fa_1$ and then that $Fa_n \implies Ga_{n+1}$. So we get that $Fa_1 \implies Ga_2$. But then we're stuck! There's nothing that implies $Ga_{3}$ because we have no way of proving $Fa_2$ from what we're given.

Comment: @csch2 I'm not sure where my notation went wrong, so let me try to illustrate the argument with an example. We have 10 balls which are either red or orange (let red = F, and orange = G in my original post). We want to show that if we assume that the first ball is red, and further that if a ball is red, then the ball after it is orange, it follows that the 10th ball is orange. This is obviously a bad argument. I am just looking for a way to articulate why it is not valid.

Comment: @JonHales, yes, that is the problem. Is there a more general way of describing the violation that this argument makes?

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity, I might just say something like "Step 3 is not valid because the hypotheses required for induction are not met."

Comment: @JonHales Why do we need to prove a2 in order to show that Ga3? If it is true that Fa2, then Ga3 follows. If it is false that Fa2, then the conditional has a false antecedent, and so the consequent would still follow, would it not? If so, then we get Ga3 either way. Edit: Sorry, I do not know how to format subscripts in the comments.

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity You should look at MPW's answer, it says exactly what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

The argument fails simply because it is not induction. An inductive argument is of the form

- Prove that $P(1)$ is true
- Prove that if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is also true
- Conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$

Your argument is not of this form.

(Here, $P(k)$ is a statement about $k$ which is unambiguously either true or false for any particular given positive integer $k$.)

Answer (score 0):

Given a proposition $P(n)$, say you want to show that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Induction states that it suffices to show the following:

1. $P(1)$ is true
2. If $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true

One failure of your argument is that you seem to be confused about what exactly is the proposition $P(n)$. Say you know that $F(1)\implies G(1)$, and that $F(k)\implies G(k)$. We cannot extrapolate to say that $G(k)\implies G(k+1)$. This seems to be the form of your argument.

In your example from the comments, say you assume ball $1$ to be red and ball $2$ to be orange. Also assume that if ball $k$ is red, then ball $k+1$ is orange. With this information, what color is ball $3$? Is it red? Orange? We don't know - we don't have enough information to make any statements about the color.